# Javascript - when an <option> is chosen, perform an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

forgive me, but I don't know javascript much and I'm fumbling through a project without help. I am trying to implement a Shopatron Add to Cart functionality on our site. The code they provided is super simple, but only allows one product sku per page. I have multiple products on the page.

They instructed this for the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Shopatron('#atc_button_div_id').addToCartButton({
    partNumber: '1234'
  }, {
    clickSuccess: function() {
      alert('Successfully added item to cart');
    }
  });
});
```

And this will add the "add to cart" button on the page:

```
<div id="atc_button_div_id"></div>
```

So they only allow product "1234" to pass and that's it. I need a dropdown , and when a product is chosen from the list, that part number goes into the cart, like:

```
<select><option value="1234">Product 1</option>
```

Product 2
Product 3

I would be SO happy for some help!!! Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `onchange` event of your `<select>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you might need to adapt it for your Shopatron code - but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

**HTML**

```
<select name='products'>
    <option value='123'>Tea</option>
    <option value='456'>Coffee</option>
    <option value='789'>Sugar</option>
</select>
```

Since you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your Shopatron gubbins here
    Shopatron('#atc_button_div_id').addToCartButton({
        partNumber: selected // <- this is your selected part number
        }, {
            clickSuccess: function() {
            alert('Successfully added item to cart');
        }
    });


    // Handler for on change event
    $('select[name="products"]').change(function() {

        // Store $(this) in var element
        var element = $(this);

        // Store the selected option in var selected
        var selected = element.children('option:selected').val();

        // You can now access the selected element
        alert(selected);   

        // Look for a way for dynamically passing var selected into Shopatron
        // in the API docs: http://developer.shopatron.com/files/Add_To_Cart_JavaScript_API_Guide_V2_2.pdf

    });

});
```

Docs for jQuery .change() [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/), and the :selected Selector [here](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

your html:

```
<select name='ddlProduct'>
 <option value='Product1'>Product 1</option>
 <option value='Product2'>Product 3</option>
 <option value='Product3'>Product 3</option>
</select>
```

and your jquery code:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", "select[name='ddlProduct']", function () {
      alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```